# Android 12 MediaStore cannot read audio files from the SD card on a specific device

Tags: java, android, mediastore

I am currently developing an MP3 player app, but I'm encountering a problem with reading music files from the SD card through MediaStore on a specific device. To verify if the SD card is recognized properly, I used SDCardEventReceiver, and it confirmed that the SD card detection and path display are functioning correctly.

Apart from the problematic device, the app operates smoothly on the Galaxy A34 and an Android Virtual Device (AVD), successfully reading and playing music files. This indicates that the issue is isolated to a particular device.

I attempted to use MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI to load content from the external storage, but it failed to retrieve any content.

Read permissions have been correctly set on all test devices, and the operating system in use is Android 12. I have yet to identify the specific cause of the problem and am seeking assistance in finding a solution.

Android12 Device.

Comment: Very well you did not tell which specific device.

Comment: Very well you did not tell how you use EXTERNAL_CONTENT_,URI.

Comment: `, I used SDCardEventReceiver, ` Never heard of that. Very well you did not post its code and did not tell that path.

Comment: `have yet to identify the specific cause of the problem and am seeking assistance in finding a solution.` Very well and that all without any code. Great.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.